# why all date fields are inserted as 1970-01-01

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHP-EXEL library to import excel files.everything is working perfectly,the only problem is whatever date the excel file contains **1970-01-01** is imported into the system.
i searched for related topics but nothing helped.

I am using `strtotime()` also but no help.

The code  i am using to format date field is as under.

```
    $myarray[$j] = str_replace("-", "/",$myarray[$j]);
              echo $myarray[$j];// 31/07/2013

    $consult_date_arr=explode("/",$myarray[$j]);
            print_r($consult_date_arr);//Array ( [0] => 31 [1] => 07 [2] => 2013 ) 

    $myarray[$j]=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($consult_date_arr[0]));
          echo $myarray[$j];// 1970-01-01 


    $myarray[$j]=trim($myarray[$j]," ");
```

Example:31-07-2013 is inserted as 1970-01-01.

what i am missing.?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you should use DateTime so you don't have to do any of these unnecessary explodes and work with arrays.

Comment: ... and DateTime will know that format, since you can tell it what format your date is in (`DateTime::createFromFormat();`)

Comment: why use strtotime? `$myarray[$j]="{$consult_date_arr[2]}-{$consult_date_arr[1]}-{$consult_date_arr[0]}";`

Comment: if you are going to use `DateTime` watch out for timezone offset. `DateTime` is timezone aware!

Comment: If you're using PHPExcel, how are you getting the date cells from the Worksheet object? Are you reading the formatted or the raw data? If raw, how are you converting the Excel timestamp to a YYYY-MM-DD formatted date?

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for the response.i am taking raw data and using date('Y-m-d',strtotime($consult_date_arr[0])); i am trying to convert them to YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: If the raw date values read from a cell are MS Excel date/timestamp values such as `41735.0`, then you need to convert them to a Unix timestamp value or a PHP DateTime object using PHPExcel's built-in `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP` or `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject()` methods, and they can then be converted to a formatted straing using `date()` or `DateTime::format()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `$consult_date_arr[0]` doesn't hold what you think it does.  `strtotime` is failing and returning a timestamp of 0 (which represents January 1st, 1970).

Dump out the contents of `$consult_date_arr` and verify it holds something that `strtotime` can digest.

**Update**

```
$consult_date_arr=explode("/",$myarray[$j]);
        print_r($consult_date_arr);//Array ( [0] => 31 [1] => 07 [2] => 2013 ) 

$myarray[$j]=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($consult_date_arr[0]));
      echo $myarray[$j];// 1970-01-01
```

You are passing the value `31` to `strtotime`, which is literally asking for the timestamp of 31 seconds past midnight of January 1st, 1970.  You shouldn't have to explode it at all, just call `strototime($myarray[$j])`.

Depending on the source of these date strings, though, you may wind up confusing `strtotime` (i.e., how should it interpret 7/8/2013.. is that the 8th of July or the 7th of August?)

**Update x2**

From the PHP manual for [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

Comment: thanks for the response one question "Depending on the source of these date strings, though, you may wind up confusing strtotime (i.e., how should it interpret 7/8/2013.. is that the 8th of July or the 7th of August?)" how to resolve your this mentioned point?

Comment: My personal solution would not to be storing date strings at all, and rather store the integer timestamps instead.  This may not be possible for you.  See my second update for how the function by default will disambiguate by default.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try strtotime() directly and then format using date()?  Don't replace/explode anything on $myarray, just use this line for every element of the array:

```
$myarray[$j] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($myarray[$j]));
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Hey no need to replace '-' to '/'.

use this directly.

```
  $myarray[$j] = str_replace("-", "/",$myarray[$j]);
  $myarray[$j]=trim($myarray[$j]," ");
```

Answer (score 1):

that means you are passing wrong format of date....

e.g

```
Your database have dd-mm-yyyy format and you are trying to pass data in mm-dd-yyyy format...
```

in short you are passing wrong date format

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this. this should work for you. You don't need `strtotime` and `date` functions.

```
$myarray[$j] = str_replace("-", "/",$myarray[$j]);
          echo $myarray[$j];// 31/07/2013

$consult_date_arr=explode("/",$myarray[$j]);
        print_r($consult_date_arr);//Array ( [0] => 31 [1] => 07 [2] => 2013 ) 
//you have all the components so no need to convert to time and back to string
$myarray[$j]="{$consult_date_arr[2]}-{$consult_date_arr[1]}-{$consult_date_arr[‌​0]}";
      echo $myarray[$j];// should be 2013-07-31


$myarray[$j]=trim($myarray[$j]," ");
```